# Yii2 Kartik EditableColumn Dropdown Relation Returns wrong Value

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I have an issue with a Gridview using kartik\grid\EditableColumn, after changing the value I am returned the wrong value for the column when it updates. I am returned the dropdown key/main table integer rather than the string contained in a linked table.

I have two tables

Leads - columns id and status_id

Related fields - model, field, related_value, related_value

The relation is based on in this case

```
model:"Leads",
field:"status_id",
related_id:status_id
```

I have the following relation in my model

```
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(RelatedFields::className(), ["related_id" => "status_id"])->andOnCondition(["status.field" => "status_id", "status.model"=>"Leads"])->from(["status" => RelatedFields::tableName()]);
}
```

I also created the following as a test based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537619/how-to-use-yii2-kartik-gridview-editable-column-with-mulitple-model-relations)

```
public function getStatusValue()
{
    return $this->status->related_value;
}
```

Here is the column code

```
[
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'status_id',
        'value'=>'status.related_value',
        //'value' => function($model){ return $model->status->related_value; },
        //'value' => function($model){ return $model->StatusValue; },
        //'refreshGrid' => true,//Works but not nice
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'center',
        'pageSummary' => true,
        'readonly' => false,
        'width'=>'10%',
        'filter'=>Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'status', ArrayHelper::map(RelatedFields::Find()->where(['model' =>"Leads","field"=>"status_id"])->all(), 'related_id', 'related_value'),['class' => 'form-control','prompt' => Yii::t('app', '')]),
        'editableOptions'=> [
            //'attribute'=>'status_id',
            //'value'=>'status.related_value',
          //'header' => 'profile',
          //'format' => Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,
          'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
          'data'=> ArrayHelper::map(RelatedFields::Find()->where(['model' =>"Leads","field"=>"status_id"])->all(), 'related_id', 'related_value'),
        ]
    ],
```

Commented out are a number of lines in my attempts to fix the issue as well as  combinations of them, however all result in the wrong value.

If for example I select the related value "New" which has a related_id 1, after the column has been updated I get the value 1 instead of "New".

When the table is first loaded/reloaded the value does show correctly.

I could reload the grid, but this seems wrong just to fix 1% of the data shown on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I your model take a public variable `$status_value`

create an assigning value method

```
public function getStatusValue()(){
    return $this->status_value= $this->status->related_value;
}
```

Now in `Gridview` use getStatusValue`enter code here`method with assigning value as below

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
   $gridColumns = [
   [
   'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
   'attribute' => 'status_value',
   'pageSummary' => true,
   'readonly' => false,
   'value' => function($model){ return $model->statusValue; }, // assign value from getStatusValue method
   'editableOptions' => [
        'header' => 'status_value',
        'inputType' => kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
        'options' => [
            'pluginOptions' => [

            ]
        ]
    ],
],  

];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow Kartik [guide](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#editable-column-action), he suggest to add `EditableColumnAction` to better handle the editable column:

> The EditableColumnAction offers a quick easy way to setup your
>   controller action for updating, saving and managing the EditableColumn
>   output from GridView. This action class extends from yii\rest\Action
>   and hence all properties available with yii\rest\Action are applicable
>   here. The basic setup of the column involves setting up the controller
>   action and the EditableColumn.

So you need to add an `EditableColumnAction` in your controller to handle the update of the model:

```
public function actions()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::actions(), [
        'edit-lead' => [
            'class' => EditableColumnAction::class,
            'modelClass' => Leads::class
        ]
    ]);
}
```

> In your GridView editable column configuration, include the above
>   controller action for processing the Editable within editableOptions.
>   For example

And in your column code you need to add the action to `editableOptions` property:

```
'editableOptions' => [
    ...
    'formOptions' => ['action' => ['/leads/edit-lead']]
]
```

Now, according to the [guide](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#editable-column-action-options), you can add to your action the `outputValue` property:

```
'outputValue' => function (Leads $model) {
    return $model->status->related_value;
}
```